# How to Combine external JavaScript with Shopify website

Tags: javascript, shopify, minify

I've tested my website with Pingdom and suggested to combine external javascripts, but I don't know how to do this with shopify website.

Comment: Did you do some [investigation](https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design/t/how-to-add-javascript-files-to-shopify-168414) before asking this question?

Comment: yes, i also minified the js but still my score in pingdow wont get higher than 83

Answer (score 3):

Adding external script files for Shopify theme is pretty simple.

You just need to upload your script file to the asset folder of your theme file. Or you can create a .js file to paste your code there. After that you just need to include that script file to the theme.liquid file.

Just need to add the following before end of  tag in the theme.liquid file.

{{ 'your-script-file-name.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}

Comment: i tried to do it,but it only displays a broken site

Comment: some of the js files are not inside assets

Comment: asset_url filter will search for the file in the asset folder of your theme

Comment: If the file is in the themes folder, then it's not "external" as the OP title asks for.