# Combine external javascript

Tags: javascript

so I have a shopify store and I'm trying to Combine external javascript files that I have. I'm using the split theme and based the varvy.com report, I have 9 .js files. I followed the instruction from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087470/how-to-combine-external-javascript-with-shopify-website), but I found out the order matters in combing these files and Now I wanna know, is there a way for me to figure out which .js file should I put first and last and find their order?

External javascript file locations

[image: External javascript file locations]

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into grunt/gulp (task automation process), which combines different files into their respective type.